# use images as a icon in the input box

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I have tried different ways for this but none of them were working for me so I am asking this question.

I have a images [image]

I do have the following form

```html
<div className="login-form">
  <form className="form-horizontal" id="loginForm">
    <div className="form-group" id="username-div">
      <input type="email" className="form-control usertext" id="username" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried using the position absolute as well. but not working.

So, How can I resolve this issue ?

Any hint or help will be helpful.

Comment: Can you show me your original code where you are using this?

Comment: What are trying to achieve? add your css code too

Comment: Updated the question where I have added an image.

Comment: why you want to use image ? instead of image you can you font-awesome or moon-font or other fonts to archive this.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve this, one is to use absolute positioning and put the icon inside the input, but I prefer this way:

```css
.custom-input {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #ededed;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.custom-input>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.custom-input img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-input input {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-input">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNLAq.png" alt="user-icon" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
</div>
```

**But**, please note that it's not the recommended way, and it's better to use font-icons for this case. There are already lots of beautiful, and elegant font icons for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set background-image of the input element to use your image and then use padding to adjust cursor/placeholder position, Here's sample css:

```
    input {  
     background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNLAq.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     padding-left:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontawesome library for this use:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf007; Username" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font awesome icons in place holder as and link font awesome cdn to your page using following code

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

then add font awesome icon using its code value(CSS content Value)

```
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="&#xf007; " style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
```

and set font-family to FontAwesome